# Accessing Angular Component's DOM children

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to create an Angular reusable button component. Right now, it is used like so:

```
<fun-button
  [disabled]="true">
  [label]="'button label'"
>
</fun-button>
```

The template for `fun-button` looks like this:

```
<button>
  {{this.label}}
</button>
```

So far, so good. Everything works.

Now I would like to modify `fun-button` so that it is used more like an HTML button:

```
<fun-button>
  child button label
</fun-button>
```

How can I access `fun-button`'s  DOM children, which in this case is the string 'child button label'?

Is such a thing even possible? I've seen a bunch of answers that involve tagging the child elements, but in my case I want to accept any arbitrary children.

Thanks!

EDIT, WITH ANSWER:

Turned out to be incredibly easy, thanks MikeOne. Just made the template look like this:

```
<button>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</button>
```

And then use like this:

```
<fun-button>
  child button label
</fun-button>
```

Comment: <ng-content> is your friend..

Comment: @MikeOne. Well, that was easy. Thanks!

That's what they get for making a guy who's never done Angular do angular.

Comment: You should invest time in it, it’s a great framework! Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Made the template look like this:

```
<button>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</button>
```

And then use like this:

```
<fun-button>
  child button label
</fun-button>
```